# HTTPS Session Invalidation

Tags: php, ssl, session-cookies

I have been asked to fix and improve the backend of a online service which I did not develop.

After struggling with terrible code and nonsensical design decisions, I finally got to a good point.

However I am now confronted with a strange bug: I set the system to require SSL (everything, even authentication was done in clear).

As a result **the system randomly logs out users very often**.

Looking at php.ini session settings I do not see anything suspicious, but I'm definitely not a php expert

```
  [Session]
  session.save_handler = "files"
  session.save_path = "/tmp"
  session.use_cookies = "1"
  session.gc_divisor = '100'
  session.name = "PHPSESSID"
  session.auto_start = ""
  session.cookie_secure = "1"
  session.cookie_lifetime = "0"
  session.cookie_path = "/"
  session.cookie_domain = ""
  session.serialize_handler = "php"
  session.gc_probability = "1"
  session.gc_maxlifetime = "43200"
  session.referer_check = ""
  session.entropy_length = "0"
  session.entropy_file = ""
  session.cache_limiter = "nocache"
  session.cache_expire = "180"
  session.use_trans_sid = "1"
```

The code used to start the session is:

```
if(!session_id()) session_start();
```

which looks pretty normal to me.

Should I look for the problem's cause somewhere else?

Comment: Th issue may not be in php.ini at all - but when you actually start the session in the code, since you can pretty much override any of those settings when you actually crank the session up. Just out of curiosity though what's the `session.gc_divisor` set to? The chance of a session being garbage collected = `session.gc_probability / session.gc_divisor`; therefore if your `session.gc_divisor` <= 1 there's a good chance sessions will be trashed whenever the garbage collection routine runs. The default production value for the divisor should be 1000 in php.ini.

Comment: ... although, having said that, garbage collection should only run on sessions that are 12+ hours old according to your `session.gc_maxlifetime` value ...

Comment: I checked gc_divisor and included its value in my question. However as you said session.gc_maxlifetime should do the trick... I also added to the question the code used to start the session.

Comment: Personally I'd just do `session_start();` at the top of every script rather than `if(!session_id()) session_start();` since if there's already a session active `session_start()` just resumes that session - I'm not sure that will make any difference but I'd say it's more "normal" to just call `session_start()` without any kind of condition on it. Otherwise consider setting a value like '.yoursite.ext' to `session.cookie_domain` in case jumping sub-domains is terminating the sessions - oh, and remember to restart Apache after every change in php.ini or it won't take effect.

Comment: Hi, in fact the frontend is not on HTTPS and uses the same domain. Accessing the frontend with this setup basically kicks users out of the backend. Both are on the same domain, so I will set cookie_path to the path of the backend. This should do the trick right?

Comment: *fingers crossed* yeah, sometimes odd things happen as cookies get updated with different parameters : I generally force the parameters to what I need them to be with `session_set_cookie_params` (http://uk1.php.net/session_set_cookie_params) before starting the session ... your cookie *should* be ignored by the front-end though (as that's not under the SSL) since you've got `session.cookie_secure = "1"` - but the emphasis there is on the *should*

Comment: Hahah I love the "the emphasis is on the should" in fact it wasn't. Setting the path did not solve the problem. I've come up with a brutal but working solution: always redirect frontend to www.site.com and always redirect the backend to site.com/backend for the backend